# How to pass a variable from a query into image url, ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a query that returns a number i.e: product.id => 5

then I want to display an image that responds to that variable

image link should be: example.com/5(variable).jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<%= image_tag("example.com/#{product.id}.jpg") if product.present? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<%= image_tag("example.com/".to_s+ product.id.to_s + ".jpg".to_s) if product.present? %>
```